# How to get vertical tabs for terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am a great fan of vertical tabs which I use for Firefox. It really eases my work flow. I am looking for something similar for the gnome-terminal as well. Is there any way to get it.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** No.

---

That's (currently) not possible without changes in the source code and I assume that this is not your intention.

But the idea has something. I prefer to renounce horizontal space.

---

The only thing you can do is to switch between top and bottom:

```
% gsettings range org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings tab-position       
enum
'top'
'bottom'
```

Move to top

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings tab-position top
```

Move to bottom

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings tab-position bottom
```

Comment: :) yes definitely. Hope someone picks it up.

Comment: I tried to use your idea `gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings tab-position top 
No such schema 'org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings` but getting this error

Comment: what's your terminal version?

Comment: its gnome-terminal which is default in ubuntu14.04. Not sure of the version

Comment: Ok, so the commands do not work yet. But vertical tabs does not exist anyway. :\

Answer (score 1):

TL; DR no with `gnome-terminal`, but you can do it with `[terminator][1]`.

Install `terminator` as usual:

```
sudo apt-get install terminator
```

And then run it from the dash, right click, choose "preferences" in the menu, and you can see this:

[image: terminator preferences]

Now if you open multiple tabs you have

[image: terminator]

...where you can also see a vertical split terminal.